# Position button vertically in parent with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, button, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following button composables:

```
@Composable
private fun ImageButton() {
    Button(onClick = { }) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Image,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.load_image_button)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CameraButton() {
    Button(onClick = { }) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.PhotoCamera,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.capture_image_button)
        )
    }
}
```

I placed it in a column in my app:

```
@Composable
fun App(modifier: Modifier) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            CameraButton()
            ImageButton()
        }
    }
}
```

How do I position the buttons to be equally spaced vertically down the screen?